# Excluding sections for SoapUI coverage

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I'm using SoapUI PRO (Ready!API) for SOAP testing (surprise). In my requests I have some sections that are generally nto used by the system I'm testing, so I'd like to exclude them from coverage, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Assuming I have this structure :

```
<v11:MessageContext>
    <v11:Id>?</v11:Id>
    <v11:Timestamp>?</v11:Timestamp>
</v11:MessageContext>
<v11:SecurityContext>
    <v11:SystemId>?</v11:SystemId>
    <v11:UserId>?</v11:UserId>
</v11:SecurityContext>
```

I'd like to exclude the MessageContext part, I tried to put MessageContext in Coverage options / Excluded elements. Didn't work. I tried v11:MessageContext. To no avail. How can I make SoapUI ignore that section in calculating coverage?

Comment: Have you checked with `support.smartbear.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, it seems you have to indicate full namespace like `MessageContext@http://mynamespace.cc/path/v11`